# На чем обучать спам-фильтр?

Tags: безопасность, спам

Подскажите, есть ли базы данных спам-сообщений и нормальных сообщений, на которых можно обучить спам-фильтр?

Comment: Начинать всегда нужно с малого - сперва пусть у пользователя просто будет возможность пожаловаться на спам, при этом к вам отправится подробная информация о письме, а дальше уже думайте, как ее анализировать и делать выводы.

Comment: Обучать спам фильтры надо на реальных сообщениях, приходящих на реальный ящик. Причем на конкретный ящик. Чужой спам может не подойти. Потому, что каждому пользователю сыплется свой специфический спам. И то что один пользователь считает спамом рассылку из какого нибудь магазина (случайно подписавшись при регистрации и не зная, что можно отписаться), другой считает нормальной почтой и ждет ее прихода.

Answer (score 2):

Я таких баз не знаю. Но такие варианты приходят в голову навскидку:

- Зарегистрируйся на 100500 сайтах, пропиши в профиле почтовый ящик. Жди писем радости.
- Более быстрый вариант: завести ящик совпадающий с именем домена или же со стандартным именем в духе hostmaster, webmaster и прочее. Спам повалит, даже, если ящик не светить вообще ни где.
- Если у тебя есть свой сайт который хорошо индексируется гуглом, пропиши имейл-адрес в отрытую на нем где-то. Лучше -- на многих страницах. Ищейки сами найдут его и подпишут тебя на спам.
- Найти бота который регистрируется на каком-то специфическом движке форума. И пусть регистрируется и убирает галочку "скрывать имейл" / отмечать галочку "Показывать Ваш e-mail посетителям"
- А лучше -- написать своего бота, который на юкозе во всех подряд сайтах оставляет сообщение в котором есть твой имейл. Т.к. в прошлом варианте в основном имеются какие-либо защиты от простейших ботов.
- Автоматическая регистрация в каких-либо магазинах с помощью ботов.

Универсальный способ, который дает тебе возможность подписать на спам ящик вряд ли есть.

Comment: Последние 3 пункта спорны. бороться со спамом, самому становясь спамером не гуд. плюс к этому твой ящик могут начать писать гневные письма реальные люди. И эти письма считать спамом и обучать на них фильтры нельзя